# Check if textbox contains invalid characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I having a issue trying to check if a textbox only contains a-z 0-9 values using JavaScript.

I have a textbox on my page:

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" class="first_name" value="">
```

I am using the following JavaScript Function to check my textbox:

```
// Function to check letters and numbers
function alphanumeric(inputtxt)
{ 
//alert(inputtxt);
var letters = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/";
if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))
{
alert('accepted');
}
else
{
alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only');
return false;
}
}
```

And I am calling my function like this:

```
var test = alphanumeric(document.getElementById("first_name").value);
```

However nothing is happening.

If I alert 'inputtxt' in my alphanumeric function it returns my value I have in my textbox so I know there is a value to be checked, but it doesn't seem to go on from there.

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?

I am trying to do this with JavaScript (no jQuery).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `.value` twice:

```
document.getElementById("first_name").value
```

and `if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))`

Remove one of them.

Answer (score 18):

A few problems :

- a bad form for the [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (don't use quotes for them)
- the use of `match` instead of [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) (not a bug but not the most efficient)
- you use `inputtxt.value` but `inputtxt` is yet the value
- you never return true

You may use this :

```
function alphanumeric(inputtxt) { 
  var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (letters.test(inputtxt)) {
    alert('accepted');
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `value` twice:

```
alphanumeric(document.getElementById("first_name").value);
```

and

```
if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))
```

This basically unfolds to

```
if(document.getElementById("first_name").value.value.match(letters))
```

which is meaningless since the `String` object `value` has no property `value`, and the `undefined` entity `[...]value.value` has no property `match()` (the debug console ought to tell you as much).

`enter code here`var test = alphanumeric(document.getElementById("first_name"));