# How to test if string contain invalid string literals?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string

I have regex like this that match string literals:

```
/"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'/
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/uxqApc/3)

how can I test if given string contain invalid (unclosed strings) like this:

```
echo "asd \\\"asd && rm
```

it should match:

1. `echo "foo`
2. `echo "asd \\\"asd && rm`
3. `echo "asd \" " asd && rm " \"`

but not:

1. `echo "asd \\\"asd" && rm`
2. `echo "asd \"asd" && rm`
3. `echo "asd \\\\\"asd" && echo " \" " && rm`

How can I create such regex solution with javascript (without specific PCRE extensions) are preferred.

**EDIT**: I've solved the issue using php:

```
/(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*')(*SKIP)(*F)|"/
```

is it possible to do the same in javascript or do I need to parse the strings?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874052/check-if-textbox-contains-invalid-characters.

Comment: @Alex and what's that suppose to solve? the question is for matching numbers in string and the issue is with accessing property.

Comment: In your question you ask how can you create "such regex solution with javascript". The link I gave shows how JavaScript can be used to perform regex.

You also have not mentioned matching numbers or accessing the property in your question. Could you provide code showing what properties you need to access? Just so we can figure out the best way to access them.

Comment: @Alex not my question but the question you link is about using property and regex for matching numbers. My question is how to create regular expression that match string literals.

Comment: Sorry, just caught up. If you've solved it using PHP then I take it you're just entering in the text into a text box and posting it. If so, the exact same can be done using JavaScript by accessing the text box however you like and then just doing a regex. 

Like: 
var regex = "/(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*')(*SKIP)(*F)|"/";
if(input.value.match(regex)){
    //success
}

Comment: @Alex I'm not accessing input element of the form, my question is about regex and in javascript you don't have PCRE so `(*SKIP)(*F)` will not work.

Comment: @Alex the questions is about checking if string contain odd number of quote characters if before the quote there are no slashes or even numer of slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php pattern is actually wrong since it doesn't work with single quotes. You can easily correct it if you change the last `"` with `["']`. Note that you also don't need to use the workaround `[\s\S]` since pcre has the singleline modifier s:

```
/(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')(*SKIP)(*F)|["']/s
```

However, if the use of the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` combo seems seducing, it ends with an inefficient pattern design: a non-anchored pattern that starts with an alternation. Consequence, for each character that isn't a quote (outside of the quoted parts) the three branches of the alternation are tested for nothing.

That's why I suggest a more efficient way that checks the string from the beginning (an anchored pattern) and uses a possessive quantifier:

```php
$p = '~(?:  [^"\']+ 
         |  " [^"\\\\]*  (?: \\\\. [^"\\\\]*  )*  "
         | \' [^\'\\\\]* (?: \\\\. [^\'\\\\]* )* \'
       )*+  # possessive quantifier
       .    # a character that can only be a quote (single or double) 
      ~xAs'; // modifiers: extended, Anchored, singleline

var_dump(preg_match($p, $str));
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dDJeX5/1)

Since the quantifier is greedy *(it takes all that is possible)* and possessive *(it forbids the regex engine backtracking)*, the character matched by the dot can only be an orphan quote if it exists *(otherwise, the pattern fails)*.

Same idea with javascript, except that you have to emulate the possessive quantifier using the atomic nature of the lookahead with: `(?=(...))\1`

```js
var p = /^(?=((?:[^"']+|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[^][^'\\]*)*')*))\1./;
console.log(p.test(s));
```

---

You can also build a state machine:

```
String.prototype.unbalancedQuotes = function () {
    var p = /[\\"']/g, state = {
        e: false, // escape state: index of the last quoted escape character or false
        q: undefined, // quote state: last opening quote or undefined
        update: function(m) {
            if ( this.e === m.index - 1 ) { // when the current character is escaped:
               this.e = false;  //set the escaped state to false
            } else {                        // otherwise:
               if ( this.q && m[0] == '\\' ) // if the character is a quoted backslash
                   this.e = m.index; // store the current index
               else // else change eventually the quote state
                   this.q = this.q == m[0] ? undefined : this.q || m[0];
            }
        }
    };

    while ( (m = p.exec(this)) !== null ) state.update(m);

    return Boolean(state.q);
};

var s = '"a\\h"bcd';

console.log(s);
console.log(s.unbalancedQuotes());
```

Answer (score 1):

In php I've solved the problem using regex:

```
/(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*')(*SKIP)(*F)|"/
```

and in javascript I created parse function:

```
    function unclosed_strings(string) {
        if (!string.match(/["']/)) {
            return false;
        }
        var count = 0;
        string.match(/\\*["']/g).forEach(function(quote) {
            var slashes = quote.match(/\\/g);
            if (slashes && slashes.length % 2 === 0 || !slashes) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        return count % 2 !== 0;
    }
```